# How to exclude iframe in Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I have created a Greasemonkey script for a website. What the script does is adding a div at the end of the page.

```
document.body.insertBefore(myDiv, document.body.firstChild);
```

But now the site adds an iframe for google-ads, as a result my div appears in the iframe too, which is not what I want.

How can I stop the script affecting iframes?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Greasemonkey now supports [the `@noframes` directive](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40noframes)** (long supported by Tampermonkey and Scriptish).
Use that for a cleaner way to block operation in iframes.

---

Unfortunately, [npdoty's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1535421/331508) will now trigger a warning in Firefox's browser console:

> Warning: use of return outside of functions is deprecated and may cause failures in future versions of Greasemonkey.

Comment: That warning is not a problem, you just need to wrap your script in an anonymous function: `(function(){ ... })();`, that's a good practice anyway. Thanks for the `@noframes`, upvoted.

Comment: Changed my acceptance. Thanks for providing a more elegant way.

Answer (score 22):

I put this at the top of my scripts to avoid running on frames or iframes:

```
if (window.top != window.self)  //don't run on frames or iframes
    return;
```