# Prevent Greasemonkey script from inserting div into iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, greasemonkey

I am creating a userscript that puts a div at the top of websites. It works for the most part but when a site has an iframe, the div is also inserted at the top of the iframe content. I want to remove the div from the iframe.

Here's my code so far:

```
function createDiv(){
    var userBar=document.createElement('DIV');
    userBar.style.height='10px';
    userBar.style.width='100%';
    userBar.style.border='3px solid black';
    userBar.id='userBar'
    document.body.appendChild(userBar);
    document.body.insertBefore(userBar,document.body.childNodes[0]);

    var iframe=document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
    var content=frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document;
    content.removeChild(content.userBar);
}
```

I feel like I am running into a same-origin problem. If so is there a way to prevent my content from being written into iframes?

Comment: Occasionally, iframes will load after `$(document).ready()` so a `setTimeout` may be a good option.  Can you give an example of the issue?  Or maybe console errors?

Comment: Oh after a bit of searching i found the answer!

Comment: That's good to hear.  Feel free to post is as an answer and accept it.  You may help someone else with this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to exclude iframe in Greasemonkey](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535404/how-to-exclude-iframe-in-greasemonkey)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( window.self === window.top ) { not in a frame } else { in a frame }
```

check the above condition first before your code of inserting div

original link:

[How to identify if a webpage is being loaded inside an iframe or directly into the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t)

Comment: Yup this is the answer. Thanks!